# User.id not getting saved in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, promos and users.

```
Promo belongs_to :user
User has_many :promos
```

In my routing, I have nested resources:

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    resources :promos
  end
```

I have a form to create new promos, with `simpleform`

```
<%= simple_form_for [current_user, @promo] do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :title, label: "Título de la promoción" %>
   <%= f.input :image, label: "Imágen de la promoción", class: "" %>
   <%= f.input :description, :as => :text,  label: "Descripción de la promoción", :input_html => {class: "materialize-textarea"} %>
   <%= f.input :title, label: "Pabrasecreta", class: "validate", input_html: {length: "10"} %>
    <%= f.submit "Crear Palabra secreta" , class: "right btn" %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is, user.id is not being saved in the database, so I get `nil` when doing:

```
p = Promo.last
=> #<Promo id: 13, created_at: "2015-06-22 21:44:01", updated_at: "2015-06-22 21:44:01", title: "adad", description: "dasfadf", word_id: nil, shop_id: nil, limit: nil, image: "nevera4.jpg", user_id: nil>
```

Params are being passed "correctly" (Why is user_id after the commit?)

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4ckcpcgiKlJVFU3GmvzA1i7JrseE7Yq5IW84uqUtDH4=", "promo"=>{"title"=>"adad", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff4dec8b510 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/n1/hsg_rvx906lgk_81lrm1x5xr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150622-13699-1rmge4a>, @original_filename="nevera4.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"promo[image]\"; filename=\"nevera4.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "description"=>"dasfadf"}, "commit"=>"Crear Palabra secreta", "user_id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Have you [whilelisted the `user_id` parameter](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)?

Comment: Yes, Its in the strong parameters permit:

params[:promo].permit(:user_id,:title,:description,:image)

Comment: it may need to be `#permit(:user_id, promo: [:title, :description, ...])` instead of putting it inside the promo permit. can you print the output of your strong params method

Comment: Isin't that only for form builders? (fields_for) ?

Comment: The thing is 'user_id' is a normal attribute such as :title, so it should go inside the promo permit

Comment: Can You show a controller's `:create` action?

Comment: user_id isnt being submitted with the form, though. its coming in through the route. i think it should be `params.permit(:user_id, promo: [...])`

Comment: @PhilVarg You can do that but then you get two nested hashes instead that you have to merge...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using nested routes you need to get the parent id from the parameters and merge it with the form parameters.

When you post the form the parameters look something like this:

```
{
  user_id: 1,
  promo: {
   title: "¡Ay, caramba!"
  }
}
```

Doing `params.require(:promo)...` slices the params hash so that you only get the `promo` key.

```
def promo_params
  params[:promo].permit(:title,:description,:image)
                .merge(user_id: params[:user_id])
end
```

Comment: Edited. Don't need `:user_id` in .`permit(...)` since its merged in.

Comment: This is it. Been a long time believing the reference was being saved and it wasn't. Your answer helped me solved this issue.